# Quitar borde de Listbox en Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Necesito ayuda para quitar el borde del Listbox con el que estoy trabajando.
Código:

```
    listbox_channel_text = tkinter.Listbox(
    fchannel2,
    fg= "White",
    bg= "#222123",
    font= ("Consolas", 12),
    width= 50,
    height= 200,
    borderwidth= 0.3
)
listbox_channel_text.place(x= 0, y= 0)
listbox_channel_text.insert(tkinter.END, "Global - 00000")
```

Con el parámetro "borderwidth" da igual que lo ponga a 0 o 0.3, no se me quita el borde del Listbox.

Comment: A mi me desaparece el borde. Lo que si aparece un borde gris en el listbox cuando recibe el foco (por ejemplo, al hacer clic). Ese es el borde que deseas quitar?

Comment: prueba usando `highlightthickness=0`